# WARNING: Input Action on WSDL operation and @Action on its associated Web Method did not match and will cause problems in dispatching the requests

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Although action attribute value on SEI WebMethod matches SoapAction of WSDL Operation, I keep getting the following warning when trying to call service method from java code.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl freeze
WARNING: Input Action on WSDL operation inquirePayees and @Action on its associated Web Method inquirePayees did not match and will cause problems in dispatching the requests
```

Following is the **WSDL Fragment**

```
  <s0:portType name="billPayeeServicePortType">
    <s0:operation name="inquirePayees">
      <s0:input message="s1:custPayee50InqRequest" s2:Action="http://services.abc.com/billPayee50Service/Services/billPayeeService/#CustPayee50InqRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:custPayee50InqResponse" s2:Action="http://services.abc.com/billPayee50Service/Services/billPayeeService/#CustPayee50InqResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
  </s0:portType>
  <s0:binding name="billPayeeServiceSOAP" type="s1:billPayeeServicePortType">
    <s3:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>    
    <s0:operation name="inquirePayees">
      <s3:operation soapAction="http://services.abc.com/InquirePayeeService/Services/InquirePayeeService/#CustPayeeInqRequest" style="document"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s3:body parts="custPayee50InqRequest" use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s3:body parts="custPayee50InqResponse" use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>    
  </s0:binding>
```

and then I've a client **SEI** (generated by wsimport).

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-b01-
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "billPayeeServicePortType", targetNamespace = "http://emf.abc.com/emb/ws")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface BillPayeeServicePortType {
@WebMethod(action = "http://services.abc.com/InquirePayeeService/Services/InquirePayeeService/#CustPayeeInqRequest")
@WebResult(name = "CustPayee50InqResponse", targetNamespace = "http://emf.abc.com/emb/ws", partName = "custPayee50InqResponse")
public CustPayee50InqResponseType inquirePayees(
    @WebParam(name = "CustPayee50InqRequest", targetNamespace = "http://emf.abc.com/emb/ws", partName = "custPayee50InqRequest")
    CustPayee50InqRequestType custPayee50InqRequest);
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with this and why I see this warning? Are there ways to suppress this warning?

I tried removing Action attribute on input and output elements in the WSDL above since input element action doesn't match soapAction of the inquirePayees operation. That didn't work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your wsimport version and parameters ?

```
    /**
     * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
     * JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b14002
     * Generated source version: 2.2
     * 
     */
```

Try

```
    @Action(input = "http://emf.abc.com/emb/ws/BillPayeeServicePortType/custPayee50InqRequest")
```

or something similar in your webservice method. See [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/ws/Action.html)